# Repeat a specific item of an array

Tags: swift

How to replace or repeat a specific item (v) of an array in Swift 3 / 4:

`["A","s","B","v","C","s","D","v","E","s"]`

to get this:

`["A","s","B","v","v","C","s","D","v","v","E","s"]`

or this:

```
["A","s","B","v","v","v","C","s","D","v","v","v","E","s"]
["A","s","B","v","v","v","v","C","s","D","v","v","v","v","E","s"]
```

The reason is that element v inserts pauses (sec) between audio files (A, B, C, ...). The number of repetitions of the item v should be set via a SegmentedControl (1,2, ..., 6).

Comment: Have you tried anything specific yet? – any code you can show us? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Quick takeaway

```
extension Array where Element == String  {
    func repeatItem(_ item: Element, times n: Int) -> Array<Element> {
        return flatMap { $0 == item ? Array(repeating: $0, count: n) : [$0]     }
    }
}
```

## Detail explains

Use `flatMap`:

```
yourArray.flatMap { $0 == "v" ? [$0, $0] : [$0] }
```

Basically, this checks each element of the array. If it is `"v"`, turn it into `["v", "v"]`. If it is not `"v"`, turn it into an array with that single element. Then it flattens all those arrays, hence `flatMap`.

You can also triple a specific item:

```
yourArray.flatMap { $0 == "v" ? [$0, $0, $0] : [$0] }
```

Or repeat it `n` times:

```
yourArray.flatMap { $0 == "v" ? Array(repeating: $0, count: n) : [$0] }
```

Use playground to verify it:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
import Foundation

var inputArray = ["A","s","B","v","C","s","D","v","E","s"]
var expectArray2 = ["A","s","B","v","v","C","s","D","v","v","E","s"]
var expectArray3 = ["A","s","B","v","v","v","C","s","D","v","v","v","E","s"]
var expectArray4 = ["A","s","B","v","v","v","v","C","s","D","v","v","v","v","E","s"]

extension Array where Element == String  {
    func repeatItem(_ item: Element, times n: Int) -> Array<Element> {
        return flatMap { $0 == item ? Array(repeating: $0, count: n) : [$0] }
    }
}

print(inputArray.repeatItem("v", times: 2) == expectArray2)
print(inputArray.repeatItem("v", times: 3) == expectArray3)
print(inputArray.repeatItem("v", times: 4) == expectArray4)
```

Comment: brilliant, but does this have any limitations ? why not insertion ? what is the disadvantage of this and that ?

Comment: @Tobi Inserting elements one by one should work too, but i think for that you need to search the array multiple times for the desired element. I prefer `flatMap` just because I tend to think functionally. :)

Comment: *Claps* thats great thank you, see you on the next question :D

Comment: Perfect thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. How to set "n" of "count: n" to pauseSelection.selectedSegmentIndex?

Comment: @A.M. Does the segmented control have all the numbers 1 to 6? Or are the numbers not consecutive? If they _are_ consecutive, replace `n` with `pauseSelection.selectedSegmentIndex + 1`. If they are not, you need an array of integers storing each of the options like `[1,2,4,6]` and then replace `n` with `yourArray[pauseSelection.selectedSegmentIndex]`.

Comment: @Sweeper Your solution is perfect and by far the simplest. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert(:at:)`  using the specific index of an element.

```
var foo = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
foo.insert(0, at: foo[0])
```

**Output**

> [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

You can wrap this in a function to repeat as much as you need.

Answer (score -1):

```
let array : [String] = ["A","s","B","v","C","s","D","v","E","s"]
print(replaceItem(array: array, item: "v"))

//Method

func replaceItem(array : [String], item : String) -> [String] {
    var newAr: [String] = []
    for arItem in array{
        newAr.append(arItem)
        if arItem == item {
            newAr.append(arItem)
        }
    }
    return newAr
}
```

output : 
["A", "s", "B", "v", "v", "C", "s", "D", "v", "v", "E", "s"]

Comment: Great thanks. And how can you repeat item v 3-6 times, for example by selecting via a SegementedControl?